# Where to start with "Couldn't match type MyId with MyId"

Tags: haskell, ghc, haskell-stack

Edit: very small repro available https://github.com/dten/CouldntMatchTypeRepro

`stack test` worked fine on stack LTS-8.24 (ghc 8.0.2) and i tried to change to LTS-10.5 (ghc 8.2.2). It now fails type checking and the error message is less than helpful.

The MyId types listed literally are the same type, declared in `my-model` `makeId` is in a `testing-help` package that references `my-model` and this code is in a `test` package that references both.

*Moving the function to the my-model package results in no error* (but I don't want to, and I have the problem with other types even in the same package (always a usage in the test package))
I have read through migration info to 8.2 but nothing stood out.
Any pointer in the correct direction is appreciated :) thanks

```
test\Spec.hs:785:11: error:
    * Couldn't match type `my-model-0.0.0:Types.Ids.MyId'
                     with `MyId'
      NB: `MyId'
            is defined in `Types.Ids' in package `my-model-0.0.0'
          `my-model-0.0.0:Types.Ids.MyId'
            is defined in `Types.Ids' in package `my-model-0.0.0'
      Expected type: UserId
        Actual type: my-model-0.0.0:Types.Ids.MyId
    * In the expression: makeId "19186adb-26e5-4901-956c-f3ba11fc016d"
      In an equation for `userId':
          userId = makeId "19186adb-26e5-4901-956c-f3ba11fc016d"
    |
785 | userId = makeId "19186adb-26e5-4901-956c-f3ba11fc016d"
    |           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

edits: I have tried deleting `.stack-work` and even `~/stack-root`

the packages layout is as follows:

```
package: my-model
  library
  test-suite test
     deps: my-model, testing-help
package: testing-help
  library
     deps: my-model
```

no version requirements are set (because it's stack LTS style) and all versions of my packages are 0.0.0

edit2: they're all in 1 `stack.yaml`

edit3: sorry got package deps wrong

Comment: One is the one imported from `my-model-0.0.0` and the other is one you apparently have defined locally?

Comment: When ghc prefixes a type with a package+version in the error message, it usually means you are depending on two different versions of the same package.  GHC allows that, but it's easy to mix them up.  Try to redo your dependencies such that you only depend on one version of `my-model`.

Comment: Oh, since they're both listed as `my-model-0.0.0`, I'm betting you made changes to the package without updating the version, recompiled it, and didn't recompile everything that depended on it.  This is a dangerous workflow. (ghc distinguishes packages by a package-id hash internally, so it can tell the packages apart.  It only displays version numbers, so you can't tell them apart. This is a problem.)

Comment: i added some details about package versions

Comment: I'm getting the suspicion this is because 10.5 changes Cabal to version 2, which is resulting in more modules being built as part of the test suite which then clash with the library versions. Can't see it in any Cabal migration guide though

Comment: Can you add the output of `stack exec -- ghc-pkg list`?

Comment: i have made a repro https://github.com/dten/CouldntMatchTypeRepro

Comment: @dten I've tried to build your repo and I cannot reproduce this issue (it builds successfully). I tried ghc-8.2.1+lts-10.6, ghc-8.2.1+nightly-2017-07-31, ghc-8.2.2+lts-10.6, ghc-8.2.2+lts-10.5. Can you try to reproduce on another machine (or in a VM)?

Comment: I can release on other machines and a vm. Did you `stack test`? The test code is not built otherwise, which is what fails.

Comment: Seems like a bug in stack. That is similar to an error I got when using multiple versions of a package at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That appears to be a bug in Cabal, or at least a missing feature. I don't know why it works with older resolvers. [Issue 2800](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/2800) on stack mentions this. See [issue 1575](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/1575), [issue 4087](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/4087) on Cabal.

Comment: i think using 8.2.1 makes stack use cabal 2.0, but with 8.0.2 it was using cabal 1.24, and this is only occurring with Cabal 2.0 then?

Comment: The issues I mentioned seem to affect pre-2.0 Cabal as well.

Comment: i meant 1.26 above: also this comment mentions it is allowed since 1.26 https://github.com/haskell/cabal/pull/3422/files#diff-684698b6af4c57398afaa2c1e4194338R283

Comment: It looks like stack used to work around the missing cabal feature but for some reason now doesn't. Ended up moving the tests to another package so no package level cycle